# How to delete rows in multiple tables using pdo

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to delete category and products belong to it in products_TABLE using pdo INNER JOIN.
it works if I delete only category without deleting products.
Here is my code :

```
$catid = filterString($_GET['cat_id']);
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('DELETE FROM categories AS c
                        INNER JOIN products AS p ON c.cat_id = p.catid
                        WHERE cat_id = :cat_id
                        ');
$delete = $stmt->execute(array('cat_id' =>$catid));
```

This is the error I am having :

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter
>   number: parameter was not defined in
>   D:\wamp\www\p\employees\DelStore.php:25 Stack trace: #0
>   D:\wamp\www\p\employees\DelStore.php(25): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
>
> ## 1 {main} thrown in D:\wamp\www\p\employees\DelStore.php on line 2

I understand it says given parameters are invalid, But couldnt solve how to give parameters in:

```
$delete = $stmt->execute(array('cat_id' =>$catid));
```

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you are getting is because you have `:products.catid`
Change that to `products.catid`

Also if you want to delete the entries from both tables you shoul use aliases.

```
DELETE c,p FROM categories c
INNER JOIN products p ON c.cat_id = p.catid
WHERE cat_id = :cat_id
```

Also you need to change

```
$delete = $stmt->execute(array('cat_id' =>$catid));
```

to

```
$delete = $stmt->execute(array(':cat_id' =>$catid));
```

The above example doesn't work if you are using a SQL Server. In that case you should be using 2 seperate delete queries.

Also when you bind parameters in the execute function as an array thay are binded as stings. This might also cause some problems depending on your database structure. Using `$stmt->bindParam()` is usually a better option.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I want to delete category from categories table and items belong to it in products table, so deleting in both table. I tried your code having same error in question. I tried your code like this is well : DELETE c,p FROM categories AS c INNER JOIN products AS p ON. nothing changed in error.

Comment: update your code please in your question. If you removed the `:` you shouldn't at least be getting the same error

Comment: Codes updated I tried with your example and examples in question, Having error in question. mainly having this error in both examples :**PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1**

Comment: Thanks bro, it works, and I am thinking I am a dumb :) how could I forget that dots :(

Comment: Glad to help you :)